# Asking for the best practice for managing third-party libraries (for C++) in code base

Tags: python, c++

context: company that I am working at checked in a variety of third-party library for C++ and python. These days, I upgraded the curl library due to an issue related with curl, which is fixed in a later version.

But after upgrade, problem pop out: several python programs errors "invalid argument", which I never met in the past one year before upgrade. I suspect one possibility is we have multiple curls in our codebase, only one of them is explicitly checked-in my us, and all others are brought in by other third-party libraries.

`bazel cquery` supports it: I do see a bunch of "curl". And I know which curl function is used (for dynamic link) depends on import order in python.

I want to know for this kind of problem, do we have "best practice" or "recommended way" to manage third-party libraries, especially commonly-used ones like curl?

Comment: use something like conan or vcpkg to manage your dependencies

Comment: @AlanBirtles thank you for reply! But I don't understand how these tools could help me? I use bazel, which is also a build system similar to your recommendations.

Comment: no, bazel is a build system, conan and vcpkg are package managers